# can not launch gazebo and rviz

Tags: ros, gazebo, rviz, gazebo-simulator, gui

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi
I'm new to ROS and got trouble.
I installed **ubuntu10.04 on VM ,ROS-cturtle-pr2all.**

when  rosdep install gazebo_worlds

executing this script:
set -o errexit
#No Packages to install

when roslaunch a empty world. **then the gazebo just appears a second and disappear** .

Error Loading Gazebo
/tmp/buildd/ros-cturtle-simulator-gazebo-1.2.8/debian/ros-cturtle-simulator-gazebo/opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/build/gazebo/server/Simulator.cc:261 : Exception: Error loading the GUI
/tmp/buildd/ros-cturtle-simulator-gazebo-1.2.8/debian/ros-cturtle-simulator-gazebo/opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/build/gazebo/server/rendering/OgreCreator.cc:441 : Exception: Unable to create the rendering window

[gazebo-2] process has died [pid 2602, exit code -11].
log files: /home/michelle/.ros/log/007d349e-de48-11e1-89b9-000c2920cfab/gazebo-2*.log

my computer: 32bit, ubuntu10.04 ,graphic card:ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5650.

really bother me T-T
thank you all! I need your help !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40528/can-not-launch-gazebo-and-rviz/) by [MichelleTW](https://answers.ros.org/users/2973/michelletw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-08-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

look at [these requirements](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/requirements) and these [installation instructions](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/install)

---

Originally posted by [Sanket_Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2789/sanket_kumar/) with karma: 234 on 2012-08-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2